# Command to Redis Cluster healthcheck

Tags: powershell, redis, redis-cluster

Is there any windows `PowerShell` command to check `Redis cluster healthcheck` running on windows?

Answer (score 3):

Remoting with powershell is pretty simple. Given that you've not supplied any psuedo code/ attempted examples, I'll give you a simple piece to at least get you googling some things in powershell

```
$servers = @("server1","server2","server3")

$servers | Foreach-object {Invoke-command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock {redis-cli ping}}
```